# How to make tinymce styleselect to overwrite actual class with selected one

Tags: class, coding-style, tinymce

As i use styleselect combobox, i am able to apply many classes to one object simply by chosing each style from styleselect combobox, and I can turn off class only by chosing same class again. so all styles work like "checkboxes", and i wish to make from them "radiobuttons", i want mine tinymce to apply max 1 class to object, if parent has class, then split parent and aply class, for example
Some text here (i select "text" and set my_class2) and i wish to get result:
Some text here
and 2nd case, if i select all "Some text here" and aply my_class2 i wish to get result:
Some text here
(now result will be: Some text here
I hope it's clear now ;)
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to insert checkboxes inside the tinymce UI. You should be able to make it work using checkboxes outside the editor and link to the function the style plugin uses.

Answer (score 0):

You might, if you don't mind meddling in their code. using the formatselect option, check out theme_advanced_blockformats in editor_template_src.js and add your tags with 'class=moshe' in them.. there could be only one tag (it replaces them), so you got your radio buttons :)